# The Button Bar Overlapping with recycler view issue

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I am trying to add a button bar at the bottom of a screen which already contains a recycler view. When i do so the button bar overlaps the last item of the recycler view and if i try to click on the button bar the item under it in the recycler view gets clicked. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.owaisnizami.navigation.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"


    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:background="#F44336"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Advertisements Here"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main contains the recycler view and here is its xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had and have now solved this problem and the solution is not as complicated as I was thinking.

In the layout in content_main that holds your RecyclerView, set

```
android:layout_marginBottom="<height-of-your-button-bar>"
```

Set this for the RelativeLayout which holds your RecyclerView, *not* your RecyclerView itself.

Now, when you scroll to the bottom of your list it will continue to scroll so that the last item is not hidden by the button bar.

Looking at your layout, you may need to identify the height of your button bar so that you can set this margin accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Full disclosure, I used this solution with a NestedScrollView instead of a RelativeLayout though don't know why it wouldn't work - also, if you switch to a NestedScrollView your CollapsableToolbar will be able to collapse.

Comment: Adding a hard-coded height to the relative layout will make it unresponsive for various screen sizes. The solution will work for a particular instance only.

Comment: It doesn't have to be hard coded in that way. It just has to be a known variable. You can set it as a dimension and the os will determine which value to assign based on the device configuration. Or, I suppose you could do all of the above programmatically if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Move your button bar layout inside your content_main as below

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBar"
android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
android:background="#F44336"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Advertisements Here"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way you can be sure that recyclerView ends before button bar layout

Comment: I tried it! Didn't solve the problem! @Ragesh Ramesh

Comment: What does your fragment container hold? Are you loading fragments in it. If so add  android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBar" to fragment layout too. and why is there a fragment container and RecyclerView overlapping each other?

Comment: If you are asking about the frame layout it is useless and i have removed it! I was using fragments earlier but not using them here now! I have also edited the code above! @Ragesh Ramesh

Comment: I Have changed my answer. Try this now

Comment: I tried it but its still not working! @Ragesh Ramesh